# CockroachDB cluster maximal size?

Tags: cockroachdb

Does a CockroachDB cluster have a maximum limit of number of nodes?

Can it include millions or billions of nodes?

Answer (score 2):

Richard's answer is actually misleading.

According to the reference in his answer (https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/performance.html), the number 81 is just how many nodes cockroachlab uses to perform the tpc-c benchmark. And there's also a quote in that page saying "CockroachDB has no theoretical scaling limit and, in practice, can achieve near-linear performance at 256 nodes".

Comment: 256 is still not a lot.

Answer (score -1):

The recommended maximum number of nodes is 81.

See: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/performance.html

Comment: Thanks.... and wow. I'm quite surprised, since I've read in the CockroachDB guide that this app was modeled after Google's Spanner. And I've always assumed that Google's DB servers are thousands if not millions.

Comment: Probably best to remove this answer since it is no longer accurate - lifted from the link you posted `CockroachDB has no theoretical scaling limit and, in practice, can achieve near-linear performance at 256 nodes. `